# same ui-sref generates different href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What is the logic behind generation of href by ui-sref? i got a situation when from different places (states), same ui-sref generates different href, that causes a bug.

one of ui-sref, **which have same abstract ancestor with state it is pointing to,** appends an id to its generated href, other (which is outside) is not.

from a documentation on  [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref):

> A directive that binds a link ( tag) to a state. If the state has
>   an associated URL, the directive will automatically generate & update
>   the href attribute via the $state.href() method. Clicking the link
>   will trigger a state transition with optional parameters.

So it is basically looks for `url` of state it is pointing to, and generates the `href` accordingly. Why than 2 `ui-sref`, with the same parameters, pointing to same state can generate different result?

[more details](http://pastebin.com/ttpzVbQa)

Comment: Are you using absolute state name in ui-sref or relative?

Comment: absolute  ________

Comment: Can you make a plunker? or paste here your route definition and these ui-sref

Comment: I updated the question with pastebin.